# Run shell script as service

Tags: shell, service, sleep

I have shell script that schedule in cron job to run every 20 min.
This script use to search file file based on input in txt file ($LIST) & put in transfer folder.
Now i want to make the script execute whenever there is input in the txt file only insted of every 20 min
Then i try to put sleep in the script but the script only execute once time only.
I'm also this command
nohup ./Search_file.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &

```
#################################################################
#                     Function WriteLog                         #
#                                                               #
#          To display status with time                          #
#                                                               #
#################################################################

function WriteLog
{
    echo -e "[$(date -u)] \t $1" >> $Logfile
}


#################################################################
#                    Function SEARCH_File                       #
#                                                               #
#   To Search file for copy to transfer directory               #
#                                                               #
#                                                               #
#################################################################
SEARCH_File ()
{

for i in $(<$LIST)
do
   search_file=$(find $Search_directory -name *$i* | tail -n 1) 
   
   sleep 2
   
    if [ ! -n "$search_file" ]
     then
     
    WriteLog "The file Not Found ."

    else
    cp $search_file $TransferDir
    
    fi
    
    sleep 1
    
done
}

#################################################################
#                   Function SUB_LOCKFILE                       #
#                                                               #
#            Checks if process is running already               #
#                                                               #
#################################################################

SUB_LOCKFILE ()
{
if [ -f $Process_ISRunning ]
then
   lpid=`cat ${Process_ISRunning}`
   if kill -0 $lpid
   then
      WriteLog "The associated process ${lpid} is still alive - exit now!"
      exit 1
   else
      WriteLog "lockfile will be replaced with a new one!"
      echo $$ > ${Process_ISRunning}
   fi
else
   WriteLog "Lockfile does not exist, create lockfile now!"
   echo $$ > ${Process_ISRunning}
fi
}

#################################################################
#                       MAIN                                    #
#                                                               #
#                  Main program                                 #
#                                                               #
#################################################################  
#To check if the proces is it running already
SUB_LOCKFILE

#Start to search file
WriteLog "file searching STARTED"
SEARCH_File

#Remove Process runing 
\rm $Process_ISRunning
```

Comment: You have to put a loop in the script so that it stays running. Your script doesn't seem to have an indefinitely-running service loop in it.

Comment: Thank for ur feedback, where else i need to put looping can advice.. as already have this  looping for i in $(<$LIST)

Comment: But that `$LIST` file produces to some finite number of items. When the `for` loop burns thorugh those items, control will then pass to whatever is after the loop, the `SEARCH_File` function will return. Control passes to the end of the script and it's dead.

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate it.
It work im adding here 
n=0
while true
do
SEARCH_File 
sleep 1
done

Can you advise another thing how to validate the input in the $LIST to follow the format XXXXXXXX-XXXX.
Meaning only can search if the input XXXXXXXX-XXXX